# windows 8 data lost while installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, data-recovery, ubuntu-14.04

I had windows operating system. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 operating system by over writing windows 8. But I lost 5 GB of data which was very important.

I tried test disk tool to recover data but it couldn't recover the data.

[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Data_Recovery_Examples)

Is it possible for a linux data recovery tool to recover data from NTFS partition?

Comment: If you have overwritten your Windows 8 then you need to use your backup. You do have a backup, right?

Comment: Its possible to recover data, just use a Linux data recover tool, but data can only be recovered if it hasn't been overwritten.  Its very likely when you installed Ubuntu over Windows that exactly what happen

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the Ubuntu in the same partition where you are having the 5GB of data, then you can not restore the data from it. Since during OS installation the partition select will be formatted in order to create the Linux file system in the partition. If your data is in partition other than OS installed partition then you are having an option to recover the data from it.

Comment: there are two hard disk c and d , c has windows and the data is in d drive i have over written windows(i.e c drive) ,can i get the data